# Freeze on specific sheet during macro execution and loop through each sheet containing a specific name

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

The parts not working are especially loop parts (marked as --- not working ---). Do I have to “activate” them first somehow?

The part which displays sheet “X” and freezing the screen isn't working too.
I want to display a picture on sheet “X” with a coffee image and the message: “please wait” until the macro is finished.

I tried to avoid the “Select” and “Activate” commands.

```vb
'Variables
Dim Destbook As Workbook
Dim Sourcebook As Workbook
Dim DestCell As Range
Dim xFile As String
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xFiles As New Collection
Dim xSheets As Worksheet
Dim xCount As Long
Dim xSheetCount As Long
Dim xRow As Long
Dim A As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim Z As Integer
Dim xMax As Double
       
'On a System Error go to "Troubleshooting" and display the ocurred fault code
On Error GoTo Troubleshooting
       
'Deactivate Alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False

'Display hidden Sheet "X", select cell "A1" and freeze screen
' -------------------------  NOT WORKING  ---------------------
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("X").Visible = xlSheetVisible
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("X")
    Application.Goto .Range("A1")
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End With
    
'Deactivate Alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
          
'Delete contents for each Sheet containing the name "Data" for the selected range
' -------------------------  NOT WORKING  ---------------------
xSheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For Z = 1 To xSheetCount '
    If Left(xSheets.Name, 4) = "Data" Then
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("B5:K90000").ClearContents
        End With
    End If
Next Z
       
'Select the folder with the desired data to import
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select Folder"
    .ButtonName = "Import Data"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    If .Show = -1 Then xFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    If Right(xFolder, 1) <> "\" Then xFolder = xFolder & "\"
End With
       
'On error or no files found display the following
If xFolder = "" Then
    MsgBox ("No files found or selected!")
    Exit Sub
End If
       
'Get the desired Textfiles in the selected Folder
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = FS.Getfolder(xFolder)
For Each File In Folder.Files
    If File.Name Like "*####-##-##*" Then
        xFile = File.Name
        If xFile <> "" Then
            xCount = xCount + 1
            xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
            If xFile = "" Then Resume Next
        End If
    End If
Next
  
'File processing
I = 1
Set Destbook = ThisWorkbook
If xFiles.Count > 0 Then
    For A = 1 To xFiles.Count
        Set Sourcebook = Workbooks.Open(xFolder & xFiles.Item(A), local:=True)
       
        'Skip files with no current values greater than 2 A
        xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("C2:C90000"))
        If xMax < 2 Then
            GoTo ContinueLoop
        End If
        
        If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Name, "Stufe", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            Columns("I:Y").Delete
            Rows(1).Insert
            Range("D1").Value = ActiveSheet.Name
            xRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J" & xRow).Copy
        End If
       
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data (" + CStr(I) + ")").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        On Error GoTo 0
        I = I + 1
       
ContinueLoop: Sourcebook.Close False
    Next
End If

'Just some formatting things...
' -------------------------  NOT WORKING  ---------------------
xSheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For I = 1 To xSheetCount
    If Left(Worksheet.Name, 4) = "Data" Then
        With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J" & xRow)
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            Range("B3:C3").Merge
            Range("B3").Value = "Filename:"
            Range("B3:K4").Font.Bold = True
            Range("B4:K4").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    End If
Next I

'Delete sheet "Import data", hide sheet "X" and save file
'Sheets("Import data").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("X").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
'DestBook.SaveAs Filename:=CStr(Date) + "Analysis", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
       
'Display the occured error message and exit program
Troubleshooting: Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Troubleshooting: " & _
  Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description: Err.Clear
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should add some details about your data and/or your intention.
- Using subprocedures could simplify your debugging task.
- Avoid "On Error Goto xxx" during development as you need the error details while debugging.
- Using "Option Explicit" as a first line simplifies your debugging.

I hope this helps a little! ;-)

```
Option Explicit

Sub ActivateAlerts_ShowSheetX()
    'Activate Alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("X").Visible = xlSheetVisible
End Sub

Sub main()
    'Variables
    Dim Destbook As Workbook
    Dim Sourcebook As Workbook
    Dim DestCell As Range
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xFolder As String
    Dim xFiles As New Collection
    Dim xSheets As Worksheet
    Dim xCount As Long
    Dim xSheetCount As Long
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim aCt As Integer
    Dim iCt As Integer
    Dim zCt As Integer
    Dim xMax As Double

    
    'On a System Error go to "Troubleshooting" and
    'display the ocurred fault code
    'On Error GoTo Troubleshooting
    
        
'You want to show Sheet("X") first and then
'Deactivate ScreenUpdating
'    'Deactivate Alerts
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    
    
    'Display hidden Sheet "X", select cell "A1" and freeze screen
    ' -------------------------  NOT WORKING  ---------------------
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("X").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("X")
    Application.Goto .Range("A1")
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    End With
    
    'Deactivate Alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
       
    'Delete contents for each Sheet containing the name "Data"
    'for the selected range
    ' -------------------------  NOT WORKING  ---------------------
    xSheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For zCt = 1 To xSheetCount '
        If Left(Sheets(zCt).Name, 4) = "Data" Then
            With ActiveSheet
             .Range("B5:K90000").ClearContents
            End With
        End If
    Next zCt
    
    'Select the folder with the desired data to import
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder"
        .ButtonName = "Import Data"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        If .Show = -1 Then xFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        If Right(xFolder, 1) <> "\" Then xFolder = xFolder & "\"
    End With
    
    'On error or no files found display the following
    If xFolder = "" Then
        MsgBox ("No files found or selected!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim FS As Object
    Dim Folder As Object
    Dim myFile As Object
    'Get the desired Textfiles in the selected Folder
    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = FS.Getfolder(xFolder)
    For Each myFile In Folder.Files
        If myFile.Name Like "*####-##-##*" Then
            MsgBox (myFile.Name & " found!")
            xFile = myFile.Name
            If xFile <> "" Then
                xCount = xCount + 1
                xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
                If xFile = "" Then Resume Next
            End If
        End If
    Next myFile
    
    'File processing
    iCt = 1
    Set Destbook = ThisWorkbook
    MsgBox "xFiles count: " & xFiles.Count
    If xFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For aCt = 1 To xFiles.Count
            Set Sourcebook = Workbooks.Open(xFolder & xFiles.Item(aCt), local:=True)
            
            'Skip files with no current values greater than 2 A
            xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("C2:C90000"))
            If xMax < 2 Then
            GoTo ContinueLoop
            End If
            
            If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Name, "Stufe", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                Columns("I:Y").Delete
                Rows(1).Insert
                Range("D1").Value = ActiveSheet.Name
                xRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J" & xRow).Copy
            End If
            
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data (" + CStr(iCt) +")").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            On Error Resume Next
            On Error GoTo 0
            iCt = iCt + 1
            
    ContinueLoop:                 
        Sourcebook.Close False
        Next aCt
    End If
    
    'Just some formatting things...
    ' -------------------------  NOT WORKING  ---------------------
    xSheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For iCt = 1 To xSheetCount
        If Left(Worksheets(iCt).Name, 4) = "Data" Then
            With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J" & xRow)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                Range("B3:C3").Merge
                Range("B3").Value = "Filename:"
                Range("B3:K4").Font.Bold = True
                Range("B4:K4").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End With
        End If
    Next iCt
    
    'Delete sheet "Import data", hide sheet "X" and save file
    'Sheets("Import data").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("X").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
    'DestBook.SaveAs Filename:=CStr(Date) + "Analysis", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    
    'Display the occured error message and exit program
Troubleshooting:
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Troubleshooting: " & _
        Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description: Err.Clear
        Exit Sub
              
End Sub
```